# php sqlsrv driver is not being recognized

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, windows-server-2012

my PHP Version is 5.6 and I ve already downloaded the driver for the sqlsrv extension and placed it in the ext/ directory, as well as modified the php.ini with the new extensions.

I still get the following error when trying to connect to my database

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `sqlsrv_connect()` in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db.php on line 12

Is there anything that i've missed?

Answer (score -2):

Did you change Edit System Variable and  Windows extensions ?

You can find here : http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php

Good luck..